# "Then you know who lived here?" "Trigger."

Tags: jokes

A dialogue from the movie *Annie Hall*: ([clip](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/4ee01967-1683-4b47-846e-031e2da6f96d))

> Tony Lacey: You know who the original owners were? Nelson Eddy, then Legs Diamond. Then you know who lived here?
>
> Alvy Singer: **Trigger**.
>
> Tony Lacey: Charlie Chaplin. Right before his un-American thing.

It sounds to me like Alvy is using "trigger" to mean "Who?" "Shoot." "Tell us." or words to that effect. I wonder if this is something people actually say (or said in the 70s when the film was made) or an Allenism (a Woody Allen invention)? Or is this a joke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger was the name of a movie horse belonging to a cowboy movie star, Roy Rogers (who also had a dog called Bullet). Suggesting that he lived in the house is a Hollywood-oriented joke, typical of Woody Allen.

[image]

[Trigger (horse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_(horse))